# sending c-string to non-lvalue std::ostringstream weird behaviour

Tags: c++

Test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
  std::ostringstream q;

  std::cout << (dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream&>(q<<"hello"<<101).str()) << "\n";
  std::cout << (dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream()<<"hello"<<101).str()) << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling with: g++ test.cpp
Output:

```
hello101
hello101
```

Compiling with: g++ -std=c++98 test.cpp
Output:

```
hello101
0x4b2ec0101
```

Looks like second string contains pointer to "hello" string intead of string itself. Why?
Is it some "feature" of c++98 standard or bug in gcc?

Comment: Temporary objects created inside an expression are not destroyed until they go out of scope when the whole expression is finished (ie when the `;` is reached).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++03, the non-member `operator<<` ([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2)) which is responsible for printing out C strings, namely

```
template< class Traits >
basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<char,Traits>& os,  
                                        const char* s );
```

cannot accept an rvalue stream, so instead a member overload (inherited from the `std::ostream` base class) is chosen ([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)):

```
basic_ostream& operator<<( const void* value );
```

This prints out the address.

In C++11, there is an rvalue stream insertion operator,

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class T >
basic_ostream< CharT, Traits >& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&& os, 
                                            const T& value );
```

which ensures that the behaviour will be the same for lvalue and rvalue streams. Note that this overload could not have been written in C++03, as the only way to bind to an rvalue would be through a const lvalue reference.